# Order branches in `git branch --all` by branch name

Tags: git, logging, branch

I have a repository with multiple remotes. When I issue a `git branch --all --verbose` it shows:

```
bar                    9876de11 hello world
foo                    12abde23 description
master                 34fd4545 tony the pony
quz                    ab34df67 me, too
remotes/origin/bar     9876de11 hello world
remotes/origin/foo     12abde23 description
remotes/origin/master  34fd4545 tony the pony
remotes/origin/quz     ab34df67 me, too
remotes/zulu/bar       9876de11 hello world
remotes/zulu/foo       12abde23 description
remotes/zulu/master    34fd4545 tony the pony
remotes/zulu/quz       ab34df67 me, too
```

In this output it's hard to see, if every local branch is on par with its remote counterparts. I'd fancy an output ordered by local branch name:

```
bar                    9876de11 hello world
remotes/origin/bar     9876de11 hello world
remotes/zulu/bar       9876de11 hello world
foo                    12abde23 description
remotes/origin/foo     12abde23 description
remotes/zulu/foo       12abde23 description
master                 34fd4545 tony the pony
remotes/origin/master  34fd4545 tony the pony
remotes/zulu/master    34fd4545 tony the pony
quz                    ab34df67 me, too
remotes/origin/quz     ab34df67 me, too
remotes/zulu/quz       ab34df67 me, too
```

This way, skimming over the output to see unpushed changes would be much easier on the eye. A naive solution

```
git branch -a -v | sort -t / -k 3
```

doesn't work, because the local entries have no "/" in them for `sort` to look for.

Comment: Perhaps you could do it with `git for-each-ref`, but it might be tricky; in particular, a remote-tracking branch and its corresponding local branch may not have the same name.

Comment: That's interesting! I've played a bit with it, but haven't come up with a decent solution. However, it looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little rough, but try this:

```
git branch --all --verbose | sed 's/^[ *] //' | while read line; do echo $(basename $(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')) $line; done | sort | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Basically, we extract the `basename` of the branch, giving us only the branchname without the `remotes/origin/whatever`. We then sort by it, then cut it off of the final output via `cut`. This can be tweaked and cleaned up, but it should give you a starting point. You can also add `--color` to the initial `git branch` to preserve the colored output you'd see without piping `git` to anything.

Comment: Ha! `basename`! That's such a cool idea! I had to tweak it a bit, though: `git branch --all --verbose | sed 's/^[ *] //' | while read line; do echo $(basename $(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')) $line; done | sort | cut -d' ' -f2-`. Basically, remove `--color`, since green entries will then be found before red ones, and `sed 's/^[ *] //'` to remove the leading mark for the active branch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) The --color was included by mistake, I only meant to put it in the explanation below. Great point about removing the current-branch designator. I edited my answer to include your changes.